# Calling superclass from within subclass

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, abstract-class

In the following situation, how can I make it such that I can call the parameterized constructor of `SuperClass` from within the constructor of `SubClass`?

```
class SuperClass {

    int superMember;

    SuperClass( int superMember ) {
        this->superMember = superMember;
    };

    virtual void doStuff() = 0;
};

class SubClass : public SuperClass {

    int subMember;

    SubClass( int superMember, int subMember ) {
        this->subMember = subMember;
        SuperClass( superMember );
    };

    void doStuff() { 
        //... 
    };
};
```

Should there even be a constructor in `SuperClass` (given that it's abstract), or should I move the member-initialisation code into a separate function, say `init( ... )` in `SuperClass`? In that case, how would I then call this function from within `SubClass`?

Comment: Did you mean `class SubClass : public SuperClass {` ?

Answer (score 2):

Initialization of a base class should be done like that:

```
SubClass( int superMember, int subMember ) :  SuperClass( superMember) {
        this->subMember = subMember;       
    }
```

you even use an initialization list for members too

```
SubClass( int superMember, int subMember_ ) :  
   SuperClass( superMember), subMember(subMember_){}
```

(notice you don't need semicolon after `}`)

But before that you need to inherit from the `Superclass` like that

```
class SubClass : public SuperClass {/*...*/}
```

(if I understand your intentions right)

and after that you need specify access level to your methods and constructors, I believe they should be `public`.

Answer (score 2):

Call the `SuperClass` constructor in the initializer list of `SubClass`:

```
class SubClass : public SuperClass {
    int subMember;

// Made constructor 'public'.
public:
    SubClass(int a_superMember, int a_subMember) : SuperClass(a_superMember), 
                                                   subMember(a_subMember) {}
};
```

Even though `SuperClass` is abstract it still requires a constructor, in this case to initialize `superMember`.

In `SuperClass` the constructor must be visible to `SubClass`: either `public` or `protected`:

```
class SuperClass {

    int superMember;

public: // or protected:
    SuperClass( int superMember ) {
        this->superMember = superMember;
    };

    virtual void doStuff() = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

i have written below the code to call the parameterized constructor.
it is always better to do the initialization in the parameterized constructor itself.
One more thing you should keep in mind is that if your inheritance is private then you cannot use the init() functions.

```
 class SuperClass {

        int superMember;

        SuperClass( int superMember ) {
            this->superMember = superMember;
        };

        virtual void doStuff() = 0;
    };

    class SubClass :public/private/protected SuperClass
```

{

```
        int subMember;

        SubClass( int superMember, int subMember ) :superClass(superMember)
```

{
                this->subMember = subMember;

```
        };

        void doStuff() { 
            //... 
        };
    };
```

hope this will help you.